# On the positivity of the distance between two disjoint ellipsoids

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> Let closed convex sets $P_1$ and $P_2$ be defined as follows
>
> $$P_i := \{ x \in \Bbb R^n  : x^\top A_i x + b_i^\top x + c_i \leq 0  \}$$
>
> where $A_1$ and $A_2$ are positive semidefinite matrices. Assume $P_1 \cap P_2 = \emptyset$. Prove (or provide a counter-example) that
> $$d(P_1 , P_2):= \inf \{ \|x-y\| \; | \; x \in P_1 ,~ y \in P_2  \}  >  0$$

Comment: Note, that both sets must be compact. Therefore, their cross product is compact. The distance is the infimum of a continuous function over their cross product, and thus is always attained. Use this to see what happens when the distance is zero.

Comment: Sorry I meant $A_i$ be PSD. I will edit it

Comment: I'm not sure what you exactly mean. You mean Hausdorf  metric? Distance is usual Euclidean distance, but you are welcome show whatever you have in your mind, it might help me to come up to an idea. @LinAlg

Comment: If you mean $d(x,y) = \sum_{i} |x_I - y_i|$ that's fine. But $d(x,y) = |x_1 - y_1|$ is not even a metric. Ok how I can do it? @LinAlg

Comment: What is the definition of your metric d in this case?

Comment: @Max that $d$ is not metric is just the distance between two sets in Euclidean space. Look up the distance between sets